# Windows fax and scan default account to host name

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, vbscript, registry, group-policy

I am working on setting up a script to set the DefaultAccount value to be the host name for the registry key **HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Fax\FaxAccounts** what I don't know is if this would have to be done via VB script or if it could be done with reg add? If it can be done with reg add how can I call the host name. I am attempting to speed up a deployment process we use so that we do not have to go through these settings on 200+ machines.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "how can I call the host name". Can you explain? I've never seen anyone "call the host name".

Answer (score 0):

I have not installed Windows Fax service at all and therefore do not know how a right configured **FaxAccounts** registry key looks like in Windows registry.

However, the following command adds the computer name (host name) as default string for **HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Fax\FaxAccounts** to Windows registry.

```
@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Fax\FaxAccounts /ve /d "%COMPUTERNAME%" /f>nul
```

Execute in a command prompt window `reg add /?` for help on used command and its parameters. Executing just `set` results in listing all default environment variables of Windows in same command prompt window which includes **COMPUTERNAME**, **LOGONSERVER** and others.